# Issues Uploading To Appstore: Symbols/Profiles Not Included (LINEA PRO)

Tags: ios, linea-pro

I'm having some issues uploading to the appstore. I didn't have this issue on previous versions, we just upgraded to Xcode 10.2.

Can anyone advise? It seems to be an issue with the Linea Pro libraries.

We are using Xcode 10.2 and we haven't updated the SDK yet, we plan on working on solutions while we get some feedback on here.

I have 4 logs that apple provided:

```
- IDEDistribution.standard
- IDEDistribution.verbose
- IDEDistributionPipeline
- IDEITunesSoftwareService
```

Please let me know if posting some of the errors from these logs will help.

[image: Picture From Xcode Organizer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to you on the Infinite Peripherals developer forums - it might be easier to continue over there.

The latest iOS Linea/Infinea SDK can be accessed at https://developer.ipcmobile.com

The new InfineaSDK framework fully supports iOS 12 and the latest Xcode, so I'd recommend testing out the latest version to see if this resolves the issue.

Apple phased out support for 32-bit architectures with iOS 11. Based on your screenshot, you're attempting to build/compile an IPA using an older 32-bit libdtdev.a file. If you're going to use this older SDK, you would need to reference the libdtdev_bitcode.a file, as well as changing your build settings to support 64-bit.